# Crystal Reports error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' but only in prod environment?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, stack-trace

When I run my project locally through Visual Studio everything works fine, my XML files decrypt and are read into my crystal reports template with the PDF produced, however as soon as I publish my files to the server I get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. The files still decrypt so the error has to be related to Crystal Reports. All my references are set to Copy Local, so it should be using the same DLLs as when I test.

How am I supposed to know which line of code it relates to? Is there any way to log variables in my prod environment?

```
 [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
       CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Refresh(RequestContext reqContext) +40
       CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Refresh() +82
       CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table.SetDataSource(Object val, Type type) +635
       CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSourceInternal(Object val, Type type) +136
       CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(DataSet dataSet) +60
       OIPRD.ProcessBusinessLayer.Report.createReport(String rptName, String pdfName, String xmlInput) in C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\Report.vb:26
       OIPRD.Process.ProcessFiles.createPDFs(String pdfdir) in C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\ProcessFiles.aspx.vb:86
       OIPRD.Process.ProcessFiles.processBtn_ServerClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\ProcessFiles.aspx.vb:55
       System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputButton.OnServerClick(EventArgs e) +116
       System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +107
       System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
       System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
       System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1639
```

Additionally, why does the resulting stack trace include references to my local files? I have XXXX'd these out below
edit: I removed pdb files and those paths no longer show

Comment: Any luck with this issue? I am looking at a very similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this after placing my report viewer in the Page_Load function.  I believe my issue was caused by a report parameter being set to NULL.  You might want to try setting default parameter values to 0 or blank value ("") or initializing any null values passed to your report as parameters and see if that helps.

Comment: Surely the issue would present itself when ran locally too?